# Multiple frame layout inside a relative layout in android

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I am working with frame layout. I have to display three frame layout inside a relative layout .one frame layout below which two frame layouts. two frame layout are side by side to each other.

### Frame Layout 1

Frame Layout2  Frame Layout3

how can I design such a complex layout?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust various layout parameters experimentally. Play with them in your IDE.

Here's an approach: nested layouts:

```
LinearLayout: Vertical, match_parent, match_parent

  Frame Layout1

  LinearLayout: Horizontal

    Frame Layout2: weight=1

    Frame Layout3: weight=1
```

Comment: PS. Some people have answered your other questions. You are expected to accept the best answer if it addresses your question.

Comment: That's OK if you exclude pre-3.0 users from your user base.